# Find the limit infimum of $\frac{n}{10^{[\log_{10}n]}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Q. Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \geq 1}$, where $a_n=\frac{n}{10^{[\log_{10}n]}},~~[x]$ denotes the smallest integer greater than or equal to $x$. Find $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n$ and $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n$

Since $\log_{10}{n_k} =k~\in \mathbb N$ if $n_k=10^k$, we have
$$\frac{n_k}{10^{[\log_{10}n_k]}}=1$$  and thereby $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n=1$$how to find $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n$?

Comment: Lim inf is $0.1$

Comment: How? Why liminf is not 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\lceil \log_{10}n \rceil - 1 < \log_{10}n \le \lceil \log_{10}n \rceil$ just from how rounding up works. Therefore
$$
    10^{\lceil \log_{10}n \rceil -1} < 10^{\log_{10} n} \le 10^{\lceil \log_{10}n \rceil } \implies \frac1{10} \cdot 10^{\lceil \log_{10}n \rceil} < n \le 10^{\lceil \log_{10}n \rceil }.
$$
Dividing through by $10^{\lceil \log_{10}n \rceil}$ gives us
$$
   \frac1{10} < \frac{n}{10^{\lceil \log_{10}n \rceil}} \le 1. 
$$
We can get closer and closer to $\frac1{10}$ every time $n = 10^k+1$, for instance: in that case, $10^{\lceil \log_{10}n \rceil} = 10^{k+1}$, and we get $\frac{n}{10^{\lceil \log_{10}n \rceil}} = \frac1{10} + \frac1{10^{k+1}}$. So that is in fact the $\liminf$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac{n}{10^{\left\lceil \log (n)\right\rceil }}$$
if $n=10^k+1$ we have
$$\frac{10^k+1}{10^{\left\lceil \log \left(10^k+1\right)\right\rceil }}>\frac{10^k}{10^{k+1}}=\frac{1}{10}\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$$
Therefore
$$\liminf_{n\to \infty}=\frac{1}{10}$$